# Image path for ribbon application item

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

I got little problem with my image path for ribonn aplicaton menu item.

I got this piece of code:

```
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem x:Name="MenuItemLogout" Header="Odhásit"
                                                  ImageSource="/Resources/logoutSmall.png"
                                                  Command="{Binding RelogUserCommand}"/>
```

The thing i want is: the right path of image. Because in this case, Visual Studio cant find that path. This are two different project. The one where i using this ribbon is called Z05.WPF.WeighingSystem in folder 01_LoadingPlace/ViewAnnouncedVehicles - in this folder i have particular xaml and view model.

And i have another project called Z05.DesktopApplication where i have folder called Resources and there i have all of my images. I also tried to use this path:

```
pack://application:,,,/Resources/
```

But its also doesnt work.
Any tips? Thanks! :)

Comment: See *Referenced Assembly Resource File* in [Resource File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris)

Comment: Its working right now -.-